# how to pass marathi value using jquery ajax to jsp page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, unicode, send

I want to Pass marathi name to jsp page, i tried almost everything for it. my jsp page, database, table everything is set to utf-8, but still i got O/P as ???? like this

```
$('#btnEducation2').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name").val();

    $.ajax({

        url: "UploadEducationDetails.jsp",
        type: "get",

        data: {
            name : name
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $("#tdEducationList").html(data).slideDown('slow');
            $("#tdEducationList").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your database column datatype must support unicode data e.g. NVARCHAR in sql

Comment: `urldecode`  the data and it'll show properly